# Not correct conversion svg->png using php code

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

My svg file [(m.svg)](https://ucarecdn.com/bc3d17b0-9a83-406f-bab5-d40704f0d075/)

I got some variants of svg->png conversation.

First variant of png (right version):

[image]

Second variant of png:

[image]

Third variant of png:

[image]

First variant of png was made by convert command. The second variant was made by PHP code.

*My programs:*

```
Ubuntu 22.04 
php 8.1.7
Inkscape 1.1.2 (0a00cf5339, 2022-02-04) libxml2 librsvg2-dev (sudo apt
install ... )
ImageMagick6-6.9.11-60 ( ./configure --with-png=yes --with-rsvg=yes && make && sudo make
install && sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib) (in phpinfo it is said that php-imagick 3.7.0 was compiled with this
version of IM)
php-imagick 3.7.0 (sudo apt install ... )
```

*Information given by some commands:*

```
identify -list format | grep SVG ->
     MSVG* rw+   ImageMagicks own SVG internal renderer
      SVG* rw+   Scalable Vector Graphics (RSVG 2.52.5)
     SVGZ* rw+   Compressed Scalable Vector Graphics (RSVG 2.52.5)

phpinfo -> ImageMagick supported formats: … , MSVG, ... SVG, SVGZ, ...

convert -list configure ->
...
DELEGATES      cairo fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lzma png rsvg tiff x xml zlib
...

identify --version ->
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-24 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999-2021 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC OpenMP(4.5)
Delegates (built-in): cairo fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lzma png rsvg tiff x xml zlib
```

*Results given by some commands:*

```
rsvg-convert -o m1.png m.svg -> second variant of png
convert m.svg m.png -> first variant of png
convert SVG:m.svg m.png -> first variant of png
convert MSVG:m.svg m.png -> third variant of png
```

rsvg-convert gives the **second variant of png** (not correct). I tested another svg files (with another mistakes) and got the same result with the result made by php code.

All my svg files are rendered correctly in the Inkscape and various browsers.

If compile IM without --with-png=yes option, then php code and convert command returns the third variant of png.

My questions are:

1. How to make php-imagick - imagemagick convert svg->png correctly?
2. How could be explained the difference in svg->png result between
   convert command and php-imagick? As i understand convert command and
   php-imagick use the same imagemagick, but the results are different.
3. How can I know which delegate IM uses by default?

Comment: The SVG file is not acceptable. Could you add the SVG code directly to your question.

Comment: svg is too big to post here. my svg file [(m.svg)](https://ucarecdn.com/bc3d17b0-9a83-406f-bab5-d40704f0d075/)